How to start an Activity from Foreground Service automatically without user interaction even app is closed in Android 13+?
I want to start an activity later point of time from forground service automatically without user interaction even app is closed for Android 13+.
I have tried multiple solutions

Started foreground Service, after closing the app, I have tried startActivity which runs after 30 seconds of foreground service.

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(activityIntent);

        }
    }, 30000); // after 30 seconds
    
    // Start the activity when the service is started
    
    return START_STICKY;
}


I have also tried calling startActivity with context

public class FGService extends Service {

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;

    }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, 30000); // after 30 seconds
    
    // Start the activity when the service is started
    
    return START_STICKY;
}



Alarm Manager in onStartCommand andsend a broadcast to AlarmReceiver


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1) {

        L.m("---- Alarm Receiver ----");
        //lockPhoneStartActivity(context);

        startNewService(context);

    }

    private static void startNewService(Context context) {
        // Start a service to start the activity
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, OpenActivityService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }



Tried with WorkManager

// .... Service ....
// Schedule the work to start after 30 seconds
        OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .setInitialDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest)

// ..... Worker Class

@Override
    public Result doWork() {
        L.m("Do work....");
        // Perform the desired action, such as starting an activity
        startMyActivity();
        return Result.success();
    }

    private void startMyActivity() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }


All above tries did open the activity when app is closed or in background and did not throw any error.
Is there any way to open an activity when app is closed and It should open without user interaction in Android 13 or above?
